# Display problem with Visual Studio under ssis with a remote connection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssis, remote-desktop

I have a display problem in Visual Studio under SSIS, and I use a remote connection with remote desktop manager in full screen and the problem is that all the blocks on ssis are shrunk there would be a parameter one an option to activate?

[image]

I also tried to resize the windows but in wines and also to restart the package but also nothing.

Comment: When you connect to your remote machine using Remote Desktop Manager, you can adjust the display settings to ensure optimal resolution and scaling. In the Display tab of the Remote Desktop Connection dialog, try different options such as adjusting the resolution or enabling the "Full Screen" display mode.

Comment: Or  open Visual Studio within your remote desktop session and go to the "Tools" menu. From there, select "Options" and navigate to the "Environment" -> "General" settings. Look for the "Visual experience" section and try toggling the "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance" option.