Visual Studio 2008 aspx page in Windows 11 scaling issue

Refer to the above screen, when I open up VS2008, the original scaling is #1. It works fine. Until I open any aspx page, it will automatically scale to #2 (Which I believe is 1:1).
It wasn't like this before and I still need to use VS2008 because of some legacy projects.

Is that a real unmodified screenshot? Do you have multiple monitors?

Real unmodified screenshot. Only single monitor. I open two VS2008, one loaded with my project, and then it shrunk once I open an ASPX file.

Do you have any accessibility/zoom settings enabled in Windows?

@GSerg Sorry, I forgot to mention, the Win 11 is a VM, and I am accessing this VM via RDP using my Laptop. There is no accessibility / zoom settings in the VM, but my laptop display is set to scale at 150% (recommended by Win11)

https://stackoverflow.com/q/76635045/11683?
